# Add a WooCommerce Product Variant with attributes programmatically

Tags: plugins, php, woocommerce-offtopic, import

I am creating a custom import script (say from a CRM system) and I need to create products and product variations.

I have been unable to find any recent snippets about how to do this in the most recent version of WooCommerce. I am able to find some outdated approaches, but these do no longer work.

Could somebody provide and example code of how to programmatically create a product variation and attach attributes to this?

Comment: See the following related threads: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47766413/3730754 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/47844054/3730754

Comment: Thanks! Why are you creating using wp_insert_post first, instead of creating using WC_Product_Variation entirely? @LoicTheAztec